# Thymeleaf switch statement including every case

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on my first Spring MVC project and I got stuck at a problem. I have 3 types of users in my application: admin, employee and customer. Depending on the type of user, I would like to have a specific type of menu for each of them. I tried using a switch statement in my thymeleaf template but every case gets included in the output and I don't understand why.

This is the code for my method in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "list/{roleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listFood(Model model, @PathVariable int roleId){

    model.addAttribute("title", "Available Foods");
    model.addAttribute("roleId", roleId);
    model.addAttribute("foods", foodDao.findAll());

    return "food/list";
}
```

And this is the code from the Thymeleaf template (each fragment will be included in the resulting page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>
<body class="container">
    <h1 th:text="${title}">Food</h1>
    <div th:switch="${roleId}">
        <p th:case="0"><nav th:replace="admin-fragments :: navigation"></nav></p>
        <p th:case="1"><nav th:replace="employee-fragments :: navigation"></nav></p>
        <p th:case="2"><nav th:replace="customer-fragments :: navigation"></nav></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I change the template to the following one then only the correct case will be included in the resulting page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>
<body class="container">
    <h1 th:text="${title}">Food</h1>
    <div th:switch="${roleId}">
        <p th:case="0">User is an administrator</p>
        <p th:case="1">User is an employee</p>
        <p th:case="2">User is a customer</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why isn't the switch from the first template behaving like the one in the second template? What should I change in the first template to be able to have a personalised menu for each type of user? Thank you!

Comment: I do know that `th:replace` is evaluated before `th:case` by order of precedence, but I'd take a closer look at each of the fragments to see why the other case statements are displaying.  Perhaps try to copy the snippets to the main page and see what's causing the discrepancy.  Order of precedence is here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence

Comment: @bphilipnyc Thank you for your help! I'll try your suggestion and see what I can do.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a problem with how you've set up your fragments, rather than the way `th:switch` is behaving.